# TypeError: 'class' object is not callable

Tags: python, class, module

I have got:

main script:

```
import music.umm

UMM = music.umm.UMM()
UMM.read_information()
```

module script:

```
class UMM(object):
    
    def read_information(self):
        # ..some code
        UMM.login()

UMM = UMM()
```

With this code, I get this error when I run main script:

> TypeError: 'UMM' object is not callable

How do I fix it?

I remove from the module this line:

```
UMM = UMM()
```

Now, the main script RUN the function module, but if the script module goes to another function, I get this error:

> TypeError: unbound method login() must be called with UMM instance as
> first argument (got nothing instead)

Comment: It's recommend not to name your variables, functions and classes with python statements such as `class`

Comment: Why do you have `UMM = UMM()`? It is overwriting the name of your class `UMM`, with an instance of the class, so when you import it in your script, you are actually importing the _instance_ (which is the last line: `UMM = UMM()`) and not your class.

Comment: Now, what should I do?

Comment: @Black_Ram Try to be as verbose as possible. What means "if the script module goes to another function"? Which function? If we don't know the circumstances, we can only guess. You could put up a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) which shows us the relations between your code parts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An SSCCE could look like

umm.py:

```
class UMM(object):
    def login(self):
        print("login()")

    def read_information(self):
        print("read_info() 1")
        UMM.login()
        print("read_info() 2")
```

main script:

```
import umm
umm = umm.UMM()
umm.read_information()
```

I didn't test it, but I imagine that this would yield exactly the following exception

```
TypeError: unbound method login() must be called with UMM instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

The reason is that `UMM.login()` is a method which expects to be called via an instance of the object.

Inside `read_information()`, you have `self` as a concrete object instance. So you could replace the call

```
UMM.login()
```

with

```
self.login()
```

in order to fulfill all dependencies.

A call to `UMM.login()` would try to call `login()` without a object instance to work on. This would work with a `@staticmethod` or a `@classmethod`, but not with a regular bound method.

Answer (score 18):

This is how I do it:

```
# Module Code
class MyClass(object):
    def foo(self):
        print "Foo"


# Client Code
from MyClass import MyClass
inst = MyClass()
inst.foo()
```

Comment: This was definitely causing me the trouble I was having. Python does this so much differently than the other languages that I use that when I see "from MyClass import MyClass" it just looks wrong.

Comment: we can't just do "import MyClass"?

Answer (score 0):

`class` is a reserved keyword for defining a class.

Try naming your class something different:

```
class YourClass(object):
    ..functions..
```

Then initialise it with:

```
var_class = YourClass()
```

Comment: You don't understand. I wrote 'class' for example, my class is named different in fact.

Comment: please show us your exact code. we don't know where to start if you generalise everything.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initiate an instance of the class.

You attempted to do that with:

```
UMM = UMM()
```

You can initiate an instance of the class by doing something like:

```
umm = UMM()
```

i.e. not overwriting the class name.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably that UMM is a module type and not a class object.
You can see it by doing

```
print(music.umm.UMM)   # will output type module
```

So the **solution** is to import it with a full path:

```
from music.umm.UMM import UMM

print(UMM)   # should output type class

umm_class_instance = UMM()
umm_class_instance.read_information()
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to create an `__init__.py` file at the same location as your module script *umm* (in this case `music/`) and add the line

```py
from . import UMM
```

This says to add the UMM class to the package in the current scope, `music.umm`.

For deeper packages (for instance `music.example1.example2.umm`) will also need to add empty `__init__.py` files to the directories that correspond with those packages. This is so Python recognises the entire directory as a package. So one `__init__.py` in `music/` and another in `example1/`. The `__init__.py` in `example2/` should have the line above.